# C++. Serialize\Deserialize

Tags: c++

День добрый.
Проект игрового движка для себя. Дошло дело до сохранения состояний(сцены\игровых объектов, т.п.), (ВНИМАНИЕ) а так же некоторые объекты других библиотек. Какие способы без сильной боли сериализовать и (!) обратно?

Comment: @VTT Нужен управляемый способ десериализации из-за сторонних типов.

Comment: Ответ по ссылке "Сериализация в С++" верный. Либо используете готовую библиотеку, либо вручную разворачиваете/сворачиваете все структуры в файл.